# sqlsrv_query stops echoing results with em dash if max length of field is filled

Tags: php, html, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query:

`SELECT * FROM Table`

Which returns the following results:

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 12345 |
| 3 | 12— |
| 4 | 123— |
| 5 | 1234 |

In the table above, the **Description** field is defined as `Description VARCHAR(5)`. I believe that my issue resides with the em dash `—` in that field. This issue also occurs with the en dash `–` but not a hyphen `-`.

The actual issue is occurring when I get to the PHP side of things. When I `echo` out the table returned by `sqlsrv_query` it will not print any fields after ID #3. I cannot figure out why it stops printing those results.

Here is the simplified code:

```
<?php
//Connect to the database
include_once("config.php");

//Execute the stored procedure
$query = "EXEC sp_query";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </thead>

    <?php
        //Loop through the current array
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Description']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        //Release the result resource
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Loading this web page returns the table:

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 12345 |
| 3 | 12— |

[Actual HTML Output](https://codepen.io/ZJensen/pen/poerJjO)

If I remove the one em dash from ID #4 then it will return the same exact results as the TSQL query shown at the top of this question. Is PHP somehow thinking that the max field length has been exceeded with the use of the em dash? Does anyone now how I can remedy this?

Things I have tried:

- Using different charsets
- `CAST`ing the **Description** field to `VARCHAR(MAX)` in the stored procedure
- Selecting only the first 2 characters from the field `LEFT(Description, 2)`
- Removing the emdash before the `echo` using PHP function `str_replace`

None of these solved my issue. It may also be worth noting that the `sqlsrv_errors` function does not return any errors for the stored procedure.

Comment: Since the problem is with the HTML your code outputs, I'd take a look there first – and include it in the question – before assuming it's something on the database side. You should also be using `htmlspecialchars()` for any output to HTML.

Comment: You question says "I have a query:

`SELECT * FROM Table`" but then your code uses a different query. Might want to confirm that your stored procedure can handle Unicode characters.

Comment: @miken32 Thanks for the input! I have included the HTML output in the newest edit. I have also attempted to replace the stored procedure with the actual query in the code and got the same results.

Comment: Well first thing I would try is proper escaping of your output, then go through the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). If it's only happening with non-ASCII characters, it seems pretty clear that Unicode is your problem. Check especially the encoding on the tables and columns.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you @miken32 for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was missing the `CharacterSet` parameter in my connection info to the database; adding that solved my issue. I incorrectly assumed that this was being defined by the `meta` tag of the HTML `head`: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

```
$connectionInfo = array(
  "Database"=>"dbName", 
  "UID"=>"username", 
  "PWD"=>"password", 
  "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"  //  <-- Added this line to existing connection info
);
```

A big thank you to @miken32 for pointing me in the right direction!